# ResNet50 Model Always Predicts 1 Class

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I am working on a ResNet50 model to predict covid/non-covid presence in chest x-rays. However, my model currently only predicts class label 1... I have tried 3 different optimizers, 2 different loss functions, changing the learning rate multiple times from 1e-6 to 0.5, and changing the weights on the class labels...

Does anyone have any ideas what the issue could be? Why does it always predict class label 1?

Here is the code:

```
# import data
# train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    DATASET_PATH+"Covid/",
    labels="inferred",
    batch_size=64,
    image_size=(256, 256),
    shuffle=True,
    seed=COVID_SEED,
    validation_split=0.2, 
    subset="training",
)

val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    DATASET_PATH+"Covid/",
    labels="inferred",
    batch_size=64,
    image_size=(256, 256),
    shuffle=True,
    seed=COVID_SEED,
    validation_split=0.2, 
    subset="validation",
)

# split data
train_X = list()
train_y = list()
test_X = list()
test_y = list()

for image_batch_train, labels_batch_train in train_ds:
  for index in range(0, len(image_batch_train)):
    train_X.append(image_batch_train[index])
    train_y.append(labels_batch_train[index])

for image_batch, labels_batch in val_ds:
  for index in range(0, len(image_batch)):
    test_X.append(image_batch[index])
    test_y.append(labels_batch[index])

Conv_Base = ResNet50(weights=None, input_shape=(256, 256, 3), classes=2)

# The Convolutional Base of the Pre-Trained Model will be added as a Layer in this Model

for layer in Conv_Base.layers[:-8]:
    layer.trainable = False

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv_Base)
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units = 1024, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

model.summary()

opt = Adadelta(learning_rate=0.3)
model.compile(optimizer = opt, loss = 'BinaryCrossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
# try to add class weights to make it predict 0, since we currently only predict class label 1
class_weight = {0: 50.,
                1: 1.}

r=model.fit(x = train_ds, validation_data = val_ds, epochs = COVID_EPOCHS, class_weight=class_weight)

#print the class labels of prediction

predictions = model.predict(val_ds)
predictions = np.ndarray.flatten(predictions)
predictions = np.where(predictions < 0, 0, 1) # Convert to 0 and 1.

np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)
print(predictions)
```

Comment: Can you change weights=None to weights="imagenet" and try again? Also, can you confirm that your train and test data are normalized in a similar manner (is the input scaled to [0, 1] in both cases? Also, can you predict the class of your train set for more info? model.predict(train_ds)

Comment: Can you use include_top=False instead of classes=2 in ResNet50().

Comment: *Why does it always predict class label 1?* Check `np.where()` statement you wrote. You round positive values to 1. This statement does not make sense because sigmoid outputs in a range of [0, 1].

Comment: @Frightera I see, that is a mistake, thank you for correcting it. However, I still have the same issue of always getting validation accuracy the same, it seems I'm always predicting the same class.

Comment: @GaussianPrior I played around with your suggestions for a while, the normalization fixed the problem. Changing the weights to "imagenet" wouldn't compile because it needed 10000 classes I believe.

Thank you so much!

Comment: @NolanDowdle: predictions=`np.argmax(model.predict(val_ds),axis=1)` is better

Answer (score 0):

Well done! I'll leave an answer here as well because I think you need to do more besides normalization.

When the weights are None (see [here](https://keras.io/api/applications/resnet/)) the resnet weights are randomized. You are using a large convolutional feature extractor (the first layers of a Resnet) but this extractor was not trained on anything. You may achieve decent performance because the Dense layer that succeeds it compensates for this random initialization but chances are it's not what you're aiming for. Keep in mind your resnet weights are not trainable, so the feature extraction will never change.

The reason I suggested imagenet weights is because you're working with images and therefore it's reasonable to assume that your convolutional feature extractor needs to extract important image features such as colors, shapes, edges etc. The fact that the imagenet resnet was trained on 1000 classes or so is irrelevant because you chop it off before it reaches the output layer, which is where the class number bottleneck occurs. I would pursue the weights = 'imagenet' thing.